# Loading english version of images for both languages

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, localization, localizable.strings

I have a localized application that uses two languages: English and German.
I have images that are named based on the topic name, for example: I have a topic in my application that is named:Toys, and its corresponding image is:Toys.png.
I have been loading the images for the topic by NSString *topicName.

Now the problem comes in the German version of the application.
topicName variable is now in German, Spielzeuge, and of course the image is not loading, because there is no Spielzeuge.png in my bundle.

I know I could have duplicated my images to have both English and German versions and it would work, but is there a way to use the same images for both the languages without duplicating them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property (e.g. `imageName`) to your topic class and use this for referencing the images. Then leave `imageName` in the localized strings file always be the english string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. As I understand, your suggestion for imageName is identical to the usage of my topicName, which refers to images. The problem is that I have a place where I display those topics, based on the value of topicName, where I do need it in the right language. Maybe I should create two properties, one for displaying (which will be localized) and one for referenceing the images?

Comment: Correct. That's what I meant by "add a property". The additional one would only be used for referencing the image. The other (`topicName`) is used for the localized string further on.